# Dynamic scoping in Javascript similarly to Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ecmascript-6, lexical-scope, dynamic-scope

I have been trying to wrap my head around Dynamic Scoping, I love that with MongoDB you have the option to scope with strings, for example (this is pseudo and has not been tested)

```js
const data = Schema.find({"scope.to.nested": "hello"})

console.log(data)
```

```sh
> [{scope: { to: {nested: "hello"}}}]
```

How would you accomplish the same thing in Javascript. Maybe something like

```
console.log(data["scope.to.nested"])
```

```sh
> "hello"
```

I have been trying to think of a way to ask this as clear as possible, so please ask for clarification if I am just pouring unfiltered thoughts onto the internet with no real coherent expectations

Comment: That has nothing to do with scoping, it's just nested property access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a JavaScript function:

```js
function getProperty(obj, path) {
    let currentObject = obj;
    let currentIndex = 0;
    
    while (true) {
        let dotIndex = path.indexOf('.', currentIndex);
        let propName = (dotIndex !== -1) ? path.substring(currentIndex, dotIndex) : path.substring(currentIndex);
        currentObject = currentObject[propName];
        
        if (dotIndex === -1)
            break;
        
        currentIndex = dotIndex + 1;
    }
    
    return currentObject;
}
```

You will need to use a function call to access the property, so for your example you will need to use `getProperty(data, 'scope.to.nested')`. If you want to do this with the JavaScript property access operator (`data['scope.to.nested']`), you can use [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Note that what you are asking for is different from [dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scope).